# pd.Series.str.lower.replace('str', 'replace_str') doesn't work but pd.Series.str.replace.('STR', 'replace_str') does?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working off of the Dataquest problem here: https://app.dataquest.io/m/293/data-cleaning-basics/5/removing-non-digit-characters

The problem's solution is to replace the column `ram` in the dataframe `laptops` with a string that can be converted to a numeric datatype by removing the string "GB".

In this problem the code `laptops['ram'] = laptops['ram'].str.lower().replace('gb','')` doesn't generate the correct answer, which I tried since it accounts for case.

However, `laptops['ram'] = laptops['ram'].str.replace('GB','')` does work. Apparently all of the source data contains the string "GB" in caps.

Why is this? `pd.Series.str.lower()` is definitely a method so why doesn't the first approach return the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) for default substring replacement:

```
laptops = pd.DataFrame({'ram': ['ss GB', 'fff GB', 'GB']})

laptops['ram'] = laptops['ram'].str.lower().str.replace('gb','')
print (laptops)

0   ss 
1  fff 
2
```

Or add `regex=True` for same in [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
laptops['ram'] = laptops['ram'].str.lower().replace('gb','', regex=True)
print (laptops)
    ram
0   ss 
1  fff 
2
```

If use only [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) it not working for substrings:

```
laptops['ram'] = laptops['ram'].str.lower().replace('gb','')
print (laptops)
      ram
0   ss gb
1  fff gb
2
```

Comment: `lower()` return string, then why again `str`?

Comment: it doesn't return a string, it returns a pandas `Series` of string, then again you have to use `str` to access string methods over the series.

Comment: @vlizana Then it should throw error, if we can't access string methods while using `lower().replace()`. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: @shaikmoeed - Why do you think there should be throw error? I think not.

Comment: @shaikmoeed - only if mixed strings with numeric, then need `.astype(str)` before `.str.lower()`

Comment: ohhhhhhhh @jezrael thank you; I didn't realize I needed to keep using the `.str.<method>` syntax!

Surprising it doesn't throw an error as @vilzana said, but thank you again.

Comment: When `replace()` results wrong while using directly on `series`. There should be some error/warning. Thanks for the explanation, plus one.

Comment: @shaikmoeed - Thank you.

Comment: @ jezrael are you able to explain why `.replace(<string arguments>, regex=True)` works where `.replace(<string arguments>)` does not?

Comment: @SamGarfield - it is similar, but different functions - .str. have default value `regex=True` so `laptops['ram'] = laptops['ram'].str.lower().str.replace('gb','')` is same like `laptops['ram'] = laptops['ram'].str.lower().str.replace('gb','', regex=True)`, but `replace` have default `regex=False`, so need add it -  `laptops['ram'] = laptops['ram'].str.lower().replace('gb','', regex=True)`

Comment: @jezrael if I could checkmark you twice I would! Thanks!